# Setting up OSRM (Open Source Routing Machine) on Heroku

Tags: c++, heroku, routes, openstreetmap, osrm

Has anyone had luck building and running a OSRM instance in Heroku? I am looking for a cloud-based solution where I can serve my mobile app. 
Their wiki page https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Building-and-Running-OSRM-on-Heroku exists but has no information written yet.

Any help or hints on how to set it up in Heroku would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged ruby-on-rails :) ? OSRM is written in C++. Maybe GraphHopper would be easier for you as it is written in Java

Comment: What did you try and where do you fail?

Answer (score 1):

The site http://jpizarrom.github.io/osm-chile/ is using osrm in heroku [1]

You can build osrm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS [2]

then make a buildpack with the binary osrm-routed, install the dependencies and download the data files from amazon s3.

Finally you add to the Procfile

```
web: osrm-routed -c chile-car.conf car/chile-latest.osrm -p $PORT
```

[1] bicycle: 'http://osrm-chile-bicycle.herokuapp.com/viaroute'

[2] github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Deployment-using-Chef